# Kafka Connect Sink Partitioning: Sub-Partitioning?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

If I run a Kafka Connect Sink, I specify a `.properties` input file, that specifies a `partitioner.class` such as `FieldPartitioner` which can partition based on a record field that is specified in `partition.field.name`.

So, what if I want two levels of partitioning? For example, I want to partition on date-time at the top level, and then sub-partition by a record field? Or simply partition by two fields? In Spark, this is actually quite common.

Based on the structure of the properties configuration file format, I presume that this isn't allowed. Is this presumption correct?

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own partitioner class and use a small plugin in production. The Confluent Platform has more recently added one partitioner class that does support multiple fields and a separate partitioner class that provides full datetime support, but if you want to do both, you still need a custom plugin. This seems a very common scenario, so I'm surprised that Confluent hasn't addressed this better. I'm used to using a custom plugin though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would have to write your own partitioning class that implements the `Partitioner` interface. It could, optionally, use one of the two categories of partitioners as a base class (maybe `TimeBasedPartitioner` or `FieldPartitioner`), whichever carries the most functionality with it for what you want to achieve.

Currently there isn't a way to achieve this type of partitioning only with configuration. But it sounds useful. Also, I'm not sure to which type of sink are you referring to, but if it's storage related, you might want to use the partitioners related code that is included in [kafka-connect-storage-common](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common) repo